# Resize buttons styled with AppBarButtonStyle

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I like the `AppBarButtonStyle` idea of using font character as button icon because of its scaling abilities, but it is of no use if i cannot resize them properly.

Changing `Width` or `Height` of button does not work, because `AppBarButtonStyle` only resizes padding between button icon and button borders. Changing `FontSize` of button does not work either.

Is there any way of resizing buttons styled with `AppBarButtonStyle` in WinRT application? I dont mind if i have to override or modify `AppBarButtonStyle`, as long as it preserves the ability to use font character as button icon.

Any useful advices will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create your own custom button from `AppBarButtonStyle` from the original in the standardstyles.xaml .

I did so to create a custom smaller button with no text and the only hard part was aligning everything: you're not adding shapes, you're adding a character, so it may not be as aligned as you think. Default Buttons contain 3 charatctes: outline, fill and glyph.

If you want, I can share my simplified code for the control.